# $scope.$on not working in Jasmine SpecRunner

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I've just started using Jasmine for testing an AngularJS app.
I believe I'm doing all the imports on the SpecRunner but I get the error:

```
TypeError: $scope.$on is not a function
```

I'm using this in my controller as follows:

```
app.controller('asstCtrl', function($scope, $uibModal, $interval, $document) {
    $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {        
        $scope.doStuff();          
    });
});

...
```

My SpecRunner test is looking like this:

```
describe('calculator', function(){
   beforeEach(module('asst'));
   it('basic', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = {},
          ctrl = $controller('asstCtrl', {$scope:scope});
     expect(scope.x).toBe(1);
   }));
});
```

These are my imports:

- public/js/jasmine-2.4.0/jasmine.js
- public/js/jasmine-2.4.0/jasmine-html.js
- public/js/jasmine-2.4.0/boot.js
- public/js/jquery.min.js
- public/js/angular.js public/js/angular-animate.min.js
- public/js/angular-mocks.js
- public/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.min.js

The app runs fine and the test runs if I remove the $scope.$on section from my controller. I must be doing something wrong in the SpecRunner or something works differently when I inject the controller. Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**

Test ended up looking like this:

```
describe('calculator', function(){
   beforeEach(module('asst'));
   var rootScope;
   beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope) {
     rootScope = $rootScope;
   }));
   it('basic', inject(function($controller) {
      var scope = rootScope.$new(),
          ctrl = $controller('asstCtrl', {$scope:scope});
     expect(scope.x).toBe(1);
   }));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an object and injecting that as the controller´s scope. There will not be a `$on` method on that object.

Instead inject `$rootScope` and use the method `$new` to create a scope:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new(),
    ctrl = $controller('asstCtrl', { $scope: scope });
```